# subquery runs really slow SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

The following query runs very quick without ttfj_wtd and ttfj_mtd subqueries. But without those added back in, they run 5+ minutes. Any ideas on how to tune it?

```
select eid, tech_id, tech_name, w_start, w_end, m_start, m_end
,(select firstname+' '+lastname from ems_nyc_employee where eid=a.supeid) as   SupName
,(select firstname+' '+lastname from ems_nyc_employee where eid=a.mngreid) as MngrName
,activitydate
,shift_start+' - '+shift_end as [shift]
,shift_start_time
,login_time
,first_ip_time
,datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time) as ttfj_yest
,(select avg(datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time)) from arr_tech a2 where a2.eid=a.eid and a2.activitydate between w_start and w_end) as ttfj_wtd
,(select avg(datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time)) from arr_tech a2 where a2.eid=a.eid and a2.activitydate between m_start and m_end) as ttfj_mtd  
from 
arr_tech a, dates d
where d.rep_date=convert(date, getdate()-1) and a.activitydate=convert(date, getdate()-1)
```

Comment: 1) More corelated subqueries 2) CROSS JOIN It could be improved, but first you should prepare http://sqlfiddle.com demo with sample data and desired resultset

Comment: Need some execution plans.

Comment: you might try [manually creating indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Comment: There is no circumstance where this would pass code review where I work. We certainly would never let it touch production. Correlated subqueries are performance killers (they run row by row just like cursors) and should only rarely be used. Replace them with derived tables or joins or CTEs. And please stop using implicit joins, Those were replaced more than 20 years ago and are a SQL antiipattern.

Comment: And please for future development, alias all the fields. Who can tell what goes to what table and it will be a mess to figure out in six months too when you need to change it. That is just a good habit to be in.

Comment: If the code works as expected (besides the performance) this may be a good candidate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code fixed up a wee bit for readability:

```
select eid, tech_id, tech_name, w_start, w_end, m_start, m_end,
       (select firstname+' '+lastname
        from ems_nyc_employee e
        where e.eid = a.supeid
       ) as SupName,
       (select firstname+' '+lastname
        from ems_nyc_employee e
        where e.eid = a.mngreid
       ) as MngrName,
       activitydate,
       (shift_start+' - '+shift_end) as [shift],
       shift_start_time,
       login_time,
       first_ip_time,
       datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time) as ttfj_yest,
       (select avg(datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time))
        from arr_tech a2
        where a2.eid = a.eid and a2.activitydate between w_start and w_end
       ) as ttfj_wtd,
       (select avg(datediff(mi, shift_start_time, first_ip_time))
        from arr_tech a2
        where a2.eid  = a.eid and a2.activitydate between m_start and m_end
       ) as ttfj_mtd  
from arr_tech a join
     dates d
     on a.activitydate = d.rep_date
where a.activitydate = convert(date, getdate() - 1);
```

First, you want indexes for the outer query:  `arr_tech(rep_date)` and `dates(rep_date)`.

Then you want indexes for the subqueries:  `ems_nyc_employee(eid, firstname, lastname)` and `arr_tech(eid, m_start, m_end)`.

If these indexes do not work, you may need to rewrite the query.  However, this may be sufficient.

And notes on formatting:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column names, but *especially* those in correlated subqueries.  It is really easy to get the correlation conditions wrong, and very easy to suffer trying to fix it.
- Try to format your query as if you'll have to read and understand it again.